# Should one say "at" or "in" the first hour of ...?

Tags: prepositions

Can you help me choose, talking about my time table, between

> "On Mondays, **on** the first hour (of the day) I have French."

or

> "On Mondays, **in** the first hour I have maths. **On / in** the second hour I have science".

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would use, : "On Mondays, **during**  First Period, I have/take/attend French class. "I have science next/ at 9/Second Period."

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use neither.

> On Mondays, the first hour I have French, and the second hour I have science.

Almost any preposition there feels awkward to me, so if I had to use something I would probably rewrite the sentence.

> The first hour on Mondays I have French, and the second hour I have science.

I'm not familiar with the school system in Britain and other countries, but in the U.S. we usually say "period" instead of "hour" to delineate blocks of time at school.  There are generally six or seven "periods" in a school day, plus various breaks.

> This semester I have first period French, and second period science.

University is different of course, but this will vary from school to school.  In most cases the schedule is irregular so you have to say the exact time of the course.

> This semester I have French Mondays and Wednesdays from 9 to noon, and then Monday, Wednesday, Friday 2 to 3:30 I have chemistry.

Comment: I understand but if you start by saying  "On Mondays, I have French ...", wouldn't you go on with "... in / at the first hour"?

Comment: Not necessarily.  You can say, for example, "the first hour of the day" which acts as a simple noun, "The first hour of the day is my most productive."  But, if I were to create an adverbial phrase to indicate the time I did something, I might include in/at/on but it's frequently optional.   I can say for example, "Mondays I go shopping"

Comment: Ok but if you were to write a text to describe what you do in your day at school wouldn't you put it in a more formal way? With prepositions that is?

Comment: There's nothing informal about these examples.  It's natural English, at least in the US.